# phpmyadmin not opening

Tags: centos, logging, vps

I have a Centos VPS 512 MB RAM 30 GB hard disk,

When I goto to my phpmyadmin, the login page comes, when I enter my username and password, and hit enter, the same page comes, again the same login page comes with no error,

Whats the problem I cant understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the result of "free -mt"

I'd take a look at your apache error logs as well.

You may not have enough memory to run your stack.

Comment: yes, My hard disk is full thanks, I ll empty it, and see if it works
:)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a new installation or has it been running for a while?  What user are you trying to log in as?  MySQL and CentOS don't (typically) share the same list of users.  Have you tried the user **root** with no password?

You can always [reset your root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic).  You'll have to shut down mysqld in order to do this, so make sure no one's using it...

---

Stop the mysql service.

`service mysqld stop`

`ps aux | grep mysql`

If there are any **mysqld** processes still running, run **service mysqld stop** again

Start MySQL with the following option.  This will let you log in as root with no password.

`mysqld --skip-grant-tables`

Open another terminal and run `mysql` to enter the MySQL shell.

`mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';`
`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Your password is now changed.  `quit` to disconnect mysql from mysqld and then press ctrl+c in the terminal in which you ran `mysqld --skip-grant-tables`.  Run `service mysqld start` to get things going again and you should be able to log in to phpmyadmin as root.